# Moving a bone within weighted mesh?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, weight-painting

I have a skeleton rig and mesh configured in blender that I have imported from 3rd party application.  The rig and mesh are already working together correctly in blender.

I would like to adjust the position of some of the bones to align with animations from another 3rd party application.

Currently 1 or 2 bones cause the mesh to deform incorrectly due to differences in bone position between the animations and the armature for my skeletal mesh.

So the question, is it possible to move the position of the bone without the attached mesh being deformed during the move and maintain the existing weight painting for the new bone position?

So for example in my rig the neck bone is positioned more towards the back of the neck surface, but the neck bone in the animation is more centered, so when I apply the animation the head of my mesh is artificially leaning forward due to relocation of neck bone.

When I try to move any bone in my rig the attached mesh moves with it

Hopefully the makes some form of sense :oo

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! you can move the bones within *Edit Mode*. this should keep all of you weight settings as long as you've already parented the mesh to the armature.

[image]

Comment: Thanks ... feel stupid now :oo

unfortunately moving the bone on my target armature doesnt seem to affect the applied animation ... thanks tho!

Comment: animations are a little trickier. :( I've never figured out how to automatically do them. I always manually remake them. Glad I could help.

Comment: D'oh ... after further testing what you suggested worked perfectly for what i needed :o)